# Is grub Installation possible offline in linux?

Tags: linux, windows, boot, grub, pop-os

Recently I have been trying to install Pop OS and it seems to be really complicated for me.
Now, I am gonna install it. After installation, when you restart, you won't be getting the screen where we can choose which OS to boot into. It will automatically boot into POP OS. So in order to correct it we got to install grub(something like that) using Linux terminal....
So, my doubt is, if I will be able to install it without internet connection. (if I type in the terminal to install these, will I succeed if I don't have internet ?)

BTW i need Linux to program in my potato computer.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You will need internet to get the package, but not `grub-install`

Comment: I have internet in an another PC. So, I would download Linux (pop os iso) and copy to my PC. So, can I do the same for grub ? If yes, please help me how. It's really needed

Comment: There's a chance that a live iso would have the grub package installed/included which gives you `grub-install` in the live environment